# (My)SQL JOIN - get teams with exactly specified members

Tags: mysql, sql

Assume tables

```
team: id, title
team_user: id_team, id_user
```

I'd like to select teams with just and only specified members. In this example I want team(s) where the only users are those with id 1 and 5, noone else. I came up with this SQL, but it seems to be a little overkill for such simple task.

```
SELECT team.*, COUNT(`team_user`.id_user) AS cnt
FROM `team`
JOIN `team_user` user0 ON `user0`.id_team = `team`.id AND `user0`.id_user = 1
JOIN `team_user` user1 ON `user1`.id_team = `team`.id AND `user1`.id_user = 5
JOIN `team_user` ON `team_user`.id_team = `team`.id
GROUP BY `team`.id
HAVING cnt = 2
```

EDIT: Thank you all for your help. If you want to actually try your ideas, you can use example database structure and data found here: http://down.lipe.cz/team_members.sql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
SELECT *
FROM team t
JOIN team_user tu ON (tu.id_team = t.id)
GROUP BY t.id
HAVING (SUM(tu.id_user IN (1,5)) = 2) AND (SUM(tu.id_user NOT IN (1,5)) = 0)
```

I'm assuming a unique index on team_user(id_team, id_user).

Comment: Oops, should have been SUM, not COUNT. I corrected my entry. By the way, your data contains no id_user 5. Here's a SQLFiddle with a query for 1,3: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19d5e/20

Comment: Wanted to provide no unnecessary data. Your solution seems to work for me.

Comment: Please don't forget to mark one solution as accepted when you're done evaluating fellow posters' suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT id,
    COUNT(tu.id_user) as cnt 
FROM
    team t 
    JOIN team_user tu ON ( tu.id_team = t.id )
GROUP BY  
     t.id
HAVING
    count(tu.user_id) = count( CASE WHEN tu.user_id = 1 or tu.user_id = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )
    AND cnt = 2
```

Not sure why you'd need the `cnt = 2` condition, the query would get only those teams where all of users having the `ID` of either `1 or 5`

Comment: Remove the `DISTINCT`, it's not needed.

Comment: result set is not dependent on user ids in the case condition - when replaced for anything else, no matter how many user ids you enter there it gets the same results depending only on cnt parameter

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
SELECT team.*, COUNT(`team_user`.id_user) AS cnt FROM `team`
JOIN `team_user` ON `team_user`.id_team = `team`.id
where `team_user`.id_user IN (1,5)
GROUP BY `team`.id
HAVING cnt = 2
```

Comment: where clause do his work and only come up with 1,5 records. where filter out 6 from result.